# SQL Server C# can't insert in to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server

The problem:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
> System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information:
> The parameterized query `(@name nvarchar(7), @height float, @heightscale nvarchar(5), @weigh` expects the parameter `@monthDis`, which was not supplied

My code:

```
public partial class Step3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c;

        string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";

        c = new SqlConnection(str);

        if (Page.IsValid == true)
        {
            Session["yourlocation"] = ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text;
            Session["dayborn"] = DDLborn.SelectedItem.Text;
            Session["monthborn"] = ddlmonthborn.SelectedItem.Text;
            Session["yearborn"] = txtyar.Text;
            Session["yourEmail"] = txtemail.Text;
            Session["Gender"] = rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text;
            Session["YourName"] = txtName.Text;
            Session["YourLastName"] = txtLName.Text;

            SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [DinoTable] VALUES(@name, @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname);", c);
            NewUser.Connection = c;

            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (string) Session["Name"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Height"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heightscale", (string)Session["HeightScale"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Weight"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weightscale", (string)Session["weightscale"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diet", (string)Session["diet"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (string)Session["status"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationDis", (string)Session["locationDis"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayDis"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", (string)(Session["monthDis"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearDis"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourlocation", (string)Session["yourlocation"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayborn"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthborn", (string)(Session["monthborn"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearborn"]));
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (string)Session["Gender"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourEmail", (string)Session["yourEmail"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yoname", (string)Session["YourName"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", (string)Session["YourLastName"]);
            NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoneyinMilions", 3);

            c.Open();
            NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();

            Response.Redirect("finish%20new.aspx", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: the parameter @MoneyinMilions is not found in query!

Comment: Could you show the schema of the table [DinoTable]?

Comment: Also stop leaving out the column names in `INSERT` statements; we have no idea what `[DinoTable]` contains or what order its columns are in.

Comment: i cant its to long to a comment

Comment: n exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The parameterized query '(@name nvarchar(7),@height float,@heightscale nvarchar(5),@weigh' expects the parameter '@monthDis', which was not supplied.

Comment: its after i add theMoneyinMilions

Comment: Why MonthDis is a string and YearDis is int?

Comment: year is 2234and month is October

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DinoTable] (
    [DinoName]          NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [DinoHeight]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Heightskale]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,

Comment: [DinoWeight]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Weightskale]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [diet]              NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,

Comment: [Status]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [LocationDiscovery] TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [DayDiscovery]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [monthDiscovery]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [yearDiscovery]     INT            NOT NULL,
    [YourLocation]      TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [DayBorn]           INT            NOT NULL,

Comment: [monthBorn]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [YearBorn]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [YourGender]        TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [YourEmail]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [YourName]          TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [YourLastName]      TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [MoneyinMilions]    INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DinoName] ASC)
);

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37147442/edit) your question and add the schema there, do not try to put important information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing @MoneyinMillions in your SQL query.

```
 SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [DinoTable] VALUES(@name, 
 @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, 
 @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, 
 @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname, @MoneyinMillions);", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Session variables that are unassigned are returned as `null` when queried. When passed as a parameter via `AddWithValue` it can generate the error you are seeing.

If the value in the database isn't required (it's a nullable column) then you can test for `null` and substitute with `DBNull.Value` using the C# coalesce operator:

```
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", Session["monthDis"] ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Alternatively, if the value is required (a NOT NULL column) then you should supply a default instead (or throw an exception):

```
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", Session["monthDis"] ?? "");
```

I made a slight tweak to the portion of the code that builds the SQL parameters (including throwing an exception if `Name` is `null` as that is the primary key):

```
//exit function if any required values are not specified in the Session
if (Session["Name"] == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Name is a required but not specified");
}

using (SqlCommand newUser = new SqlCommand(queryString, c))
{
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Session["Name"]);
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Height"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heightscale", Session["HeightScale"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Weight"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weightscale", Session["weightscale"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diet", Session["diet"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", Session["status"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationDis", Session["locationDis"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayDis"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", Session["monthDis"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearDis"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourlocation", Session["yourlocation"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayborn"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthborn", Session["monthborn"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearborn"]));
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Session["Gender"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourEmail", Session["yourEmail"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yoname", Session["YourName"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", Session["YourLastName"] ?? "");
    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoneyinMilions", 3);

    c.Open();
    newUser.ExecuteNonQuery(); //if you are not returning a result set, this is what you use.  Use ExecuteQuery() if you want to return data from the DB.
    c.Close();
}
```

Additionally, all of the table's required fields that don't have default values configured in the database must be specified as parameters in the query string while inserting. It's also a good practice to explicitly list the column names during an insert:

```
string queryString =
        "INSERT INTO [DinoTable] (DinoName, DinoHeight, Heightskale, DinoWeight, Weightskale, diet, Status, LocationDiscovery, DayDiscovery, monthDiscovery, yearDiscovery, YourLocation, DayBorn, monthBorn, YearBorn, YourGender, YourEmail, YourName, YourLastName, MoneyinMilions) VALUES(@name, @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname, @MoneyinMilions);";
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the table structure. I didn't realize the fields were non-nullable. I have fixed my answer and included the suggestions from bjones and Richard_D as well for completeness, hopefully there's some useful bits in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is your query.

```
 SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [DinoTable] VALUES(@name, @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname);", c);
```

You're adding the parameter to your query, but it is most likely null.
`NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", (string)(Session["monthDis"]));`

You'll need to check if the session variable is null before passing it in as @DevTony suggests.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when using sql connection objects, be sure to enclose them in a using block to properly dispose of resources.
        string connectionString =
            @"Data Source =(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DinoData.mdf;Integrated Security= True;";
        //if you want to use SQL Server security, set Integrated Security to FALSE.  TRUE means use Windows Integrated Security.
        string queryString =
            "INSERT INTO [DinoTable] VALUES(@name, @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname, @MoneyinMilions);";

        //normally, you'd print an error on the form to tell the user why their data was wrong.
        if (Session["yourLocation"] != null)
            Session["yourlocation"] = ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["dayborn"] != null)
            Session["dayborn"] = ddlBorn.SelectedItem.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["monthborn"] != null)
            Session["monthborn"] = ddlmonthborn.SelectedItem.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["yearborn"] != null)
            Session["yearborn"] = txtyar.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["yourEmail"] != null)
            Session["yourEmail"] = txtemail.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["Gender"] != null)
            Session["Gender"] = rbGender.SelectedItem.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["YourName"] != null)
            Session["YourName"] = txtName.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Session["YourLastName"] != null)
            Session["YourLastName"] = txtLName.Text;
        else
        {
            return;
        }


        if (Page.IsValid == true)
        {
            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //not sure why you are just using session objects.  If you've disabled session for the controls,
                //then it makes sense.  Otherwise just use the dropdown's text value directly.                    

                using (SqlCommand newUser = new SqlCommand(queryString, c))
                {
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (string)Session["Name"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Height"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heightscale", (string)Session["HeightScale"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Weight"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weightscale", (string)Session["weightscale"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diet", (string)Session["diet"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (string)Session["status"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationDis", (string)Session["locationDis"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayDis"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", (string)(Session["monthDis"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearDis"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourlocation", (string)Session["yourlocation"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayborn"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthborn", (string)(Session["monthborn"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearborn"]));
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (string)Session["Gender"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourEmail", (string)Session["yourEmail"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yoname", (string)Session["YourName"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", (string)Session["YourLastName"]);
                    newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoneyinMilions", 3);

                    c.Open();
                    newUser.ExecuteNonQuery(); //if you are not returning a result set, this is what you use.  Use ExecuteQuery() if you want to return data from the DB.
                    c.Close();
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect("finish%20new.aspx", true);
        }
    }
```

Here's a resource to learn how to work with SQL Connections.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Comment: and i had to the quary the moneyinmillion

Comment: i am pretty new at this so can you pls to explain what i should do before is suggest and why??

Comment: I would highly recommend that you try to run the query in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) with all of the parameters added and then work your way towards VS.  I would also recommend that you use Stored Procedures - that way, if you are reusing this query in different places, you can narrow down if the problem is with a missing parameter or something else. I'm going to edit my answer so that you can see what should be done along with a resource for you to learn more about this stuff.

Comment: they are not at the same page so it wont work this way

Comment: but i will try it anyway

Comment: I can help you further in chat if you'd like, but I can't really help you if I don't have more information about your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: how can i talk in the chat?

Comment: You have to have at least 20 rep in stack overflow to chat...I'm still pretty new to Stack Overflow so the only other thing I can recommend is that you post more of your code on this post and those of us who have answered your question can respond accordingly.  You'll need to add your .aspx page code as well as your code behind if you want a solid answer to your question, but I am not completely sure if Stack Overflow is the place to do this...a meta user will have to correct me if I am wrong.  But that is my recommendation if you are on a tight deadline.